# How do i make a solid object into water for a animation?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

Is there a way for a solid object to sit there for about 10s and then just turn into water?

I want to make an animation for an abject to turn into water after some time.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue, because as it stands it is not answerable at the moment. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button under the post. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.